# Share iCloud Key-Value Storage with app from other Developer

Tags: ios, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

The question might seem weird (and stupid) at first, but keep reading...

I used `iCloud Key-Value Storage` in one of my apps and now I need to Transfer this app to another Developer Account. But it's, for some reason, impossible to transfer apps if they've used iCloud Entitlements (why no warning?!?!).

So...In other words, I need to remove my original app and create a new one in my new Developer Account. But before that happen, I want my existing users to be able to sync their data to a common iCloud Key-Value Storage, but directed at the new app "container".

If, the "new" app is Live, would it be possible to point at that app Cloud Container (from my old one)? (e.g. my old app saves iCloud data to the new container).

When reading my own question I just think "this sounds like a big security breach if possible", so my guess is, no. But there's nothing in the Apple Documentation that says that this is not possible.

I'm not interested in solutions that involves users saving data on an external db (I know this is possible, but not what I'm looking for right now). Is there some way to save the data locally on disk (without being removed when app is removed) and then read it from the other app?

Comment: You can't for security reasons, as you say. This is the reason why you can't transfer apps that use keychain groups or iCloud key-value stores; they won't work after the transfer because they are linked to a different developer.

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarification!

Comment: Could you use a public database of CloudKit to read data from another app's container?